# What is the large a.cfm file located within the CFIDE images folder

Tags: coldfusion, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, coldfusion-9

What is this `a.cfm` inside the CFIDE images folder `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CFIDE\images` ? We are running ColdFusion 9. This file is using a large amount of storage space. I would say about 1+ MB per minute, 1-2 GB per day and I have to delete the file to get the storage freed up. But the `a.cfm` file is getting automatically created after some time.

Does anybody know what this `a.cfm` file is and it's purpose?

How can we stop the `a.cfm` file from taking up so much storage space?

Comment: What are the contents of that file?

Comment: Search the relevant directory for `a.cfm` and you'll find the code that's writing it.

Comment: This seems like a sign that your server has been compromised. A common attack vector is through the CFIDE folder on servers that have not been locked down properly. Another file that is either part of your application(s),  within the CFIDE folder, or even somewhere on your system disk has been hijacked or added with code that keeps recreating the a.cfm file.

Comment: Along those lines, go through the CF Lock Down guide to understand how to secure the CF server. For CF9 http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/91025512-cf9-lockdownguide-wp-ue.pdf . Hate to say it, but .. if the server was compromised, the safe approach is usually to wipe it and start over.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your comments. I found what was causing and fixed it. There was a DSN for a SQL DB with the option 'Log activity' enabled. And the Log of the database was saving to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CFIDE\images\a.cfm. I have disabled 'Log activity' and the issue got resolved!

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting what the issue was. Glad to know it was not an attack on the server.